# CSS getting extra padding inside ul

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a dropdown `ul`, using `position:absolute;`.I could successfully stick it by adding `position: relative;` to it's parent, and `position: absolute;` to itself, and `right: 0;` with `z-index:999;` so it overlaps everything.

But unfortunately, I am getting random extra padding inside the `ul`.

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/25629ee8c2739ab360703ec43eefa3ee.png))</sub>

A you see, the `li` has a red background, the `ul` has a green background.
You can see there is around 10 to 15px padding at the top.

When I created my CodePen, I had to copy/paste the whole container in order to get this bug to work here, it means that it's not the `ul` itself, but something outside of the `ul` causes it, but I am not really sure why, I've checked it a few times.

There's a live CodePen example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Dohpn

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I don’t see any extra “padding” … but only that you have given the `ul` a width of 180px, where 160px would seem appropriate, and the `li` has a margin-top of 15px …

Comment: @ CBroe - Was just going to comment on that - you'd need to either up the width of `.dropdownBox` to reflect the width of `.dropDownSelect` or down the width of `.dropDownSelect` or just set them both to `width: 100%;` and update the `width` of `#filtersContent #filterSelectors`

Comment: Also `z-index: 1;` would be more semantic than `z-index: 999;` :-)

Comment: @CBroe That doesn't do anything though, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Dohpn, Look they all have width of 180px. Something is obviously giving extra 15px padding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're forcing your first `li` element to be displayed 15px from the top of the `ul` element with a `margin-top`.

Take out

```
#filtersContent section ul li {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
#filtersContent section ul li:first-child {
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

[Updated CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hcujl)

Comment: I see, I'll just add the id of where I need the margin instead of globally calling it for section ul li

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the margin from your `#filtersContent section ul li` and `filtersContent section ul li:first-child`.

The margin-top that you have set for these is adding additional space.

Edit: Check out how to use the [Chrome developer tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/index) and [Firebug for firefox](http://getfirebug.com/). These tools will make tracking down this stuff much easier than guess and check!

Answer (score 0):

you can remove below styles. here is working code  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/amoFh

```
/*#filtersContent section ul li {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
#filtersContent section ul li:first-child {
    margin-top: 5px;
}*/
```